# Can I find out from a Javascript method, who\which DOM element called me?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<a onclick ="foo()" href="bar.html" >Link </a>

<script>

...
function foo(){
  //I want to know the href property of whoever called me.
  //something like this.caller.href ??
}

</script>
```

I guess I could just assign all element IDs and then pass my own ID to the JS method I'm calling, but I was looking for a better way.

Answer (score 19):

When the browser calls a function as the result of a DOM event, JavaScript passes an object to that function which contains information about the event. But it works a little differently in IE than others. To work in all browsers, `foo()` should take an argument* (I use `e`):

```
function foo(e) {
  var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
  //sender is the DOM element which was clicked
  alert(sender.href); //assumes the clicked element was an <a>
}
```

The first line will assign "sender" the value of the element which originated the event in all browsers.

Now, if your `<a>` *contains* child elements (for example, an image) and one of *those* was the actual element clicked, then that element will become the "sender". If this is a possibility, you need to walk up the DOM from the sender until you find your link:

```
function foo(e) {
  var sender = (e && e.target) || (window.event && window.event.srcElement);
  //sender is the DOM element which was clicked

  var myEle = sender;

  //find the parent node until we hit the <a>
  while(myEle.tagName.toUpperCase() != 'A') {
    myEle = myEle.parentNode;
  }

  //myEle is now the <a>. sender is still the originator.
  alert(myEle.href);
}
```

*You can also access any arguments passed to the function, even if they are not declared, by using the `arguments[]` array.

Comment: i like shorting over tirnary sometimes, myself...
var sender = (window.event && window.event.srcElement) || e.target;

Comment: <a onclick ="foo(event)" ... works in all browsers (ie, you don't need window.event checks if you hardcode passing the special variable "event" in the markup).

Comment: @cresentfresh onclick is semantically incorrect and extremely inflexible. See progressive enhancement techniques.

Answer (score 11):

```html
<a onclick="foo(this)" href="bar.html">Link</a>
```

Then your JavaScript would be:

```js
function foo(ob) {
    alert(ob.href); //or whatever you want to happen preferably pass an id 
}
```

Use the "this" selector if you want to pass the object itself to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The convention here is that *this* refers to the DOM element that the handler is invoked on.
So if you want to know the href of the link:

```
function foo () {
   // Inside foo this will refer to the DOM element if called as an event handler
   var href = this.href
}
```

That should do the trick.

EDIT: 
If foo is called from an onclick-handler explicitly in the DOM, i.e.

```
<a [...] onclick="foo()">
```

then the original context of *this* will be lost inside of foo. To fix this one can bind the function call to the original context:

```
<a [...] onclick="foo.call(this)">
```

Comment: Nope. <a onclick ="foo()"... simply calls foo(). The scope is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the value of the `href` attribute to the function when it is called:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="foo(this.href)">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing an argument?

```
foo(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to pass in the element as an argument to your function.  you can use

```
var a = event.srcElement;
alert(a.href);
```

Comment: That method is not cross-browser.