# Check where was the click coming from (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent div which performs a function and a child div that performs another function. Since clicking the child div will also trigger the parent div function, how can I tell if the click is coming from the child div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I find out from a Javascript method, who\which DOM element called me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831942/can-i-find-out-from-a-javascript-method-who-which-dom-element-called-me)

Comment: Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/ or http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#parentid").click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if(target != this) {
    alert("not parent");
  }
});
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: what if I have couple more attribute in the function, say function(a,b,c), what can I do?

Comment: The jquery click handler only takes 1 parameter (the event object).  See: http://api.jquery.com/click/.  If you have some other function you want to execute on click, you need to call from within the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert($(this).attr('id') + " was clicked!");
    });
});
```

This [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alr3/35wqz/) has this example...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("parentSelector").click(function(e) {

  if($(e.target).is("parentSelector")) {
    alert("parent");
  }
  else{
    alert("not parent");
  }

});
```